# How to create a Dev Hub for Managed packages?

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, package, scratch-org

What I am looking for is how to create Dev Hub for managed packages. Do we have to enable Dev Hub in our packaging org?

One thing I have heard in many videos is Dev Hub org will be enabled in partner business org. So if I have multiple manage packages, I will be able to use same partner business org as my single Dev Hub? Or for different packages I will have to create different Dev Hub orgs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a Dev Hub set up in our company org. Each managed package namespace is set up in that org using Namespace Registries / Link Namespace (see [Link a Namespace to a Dev Hub Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm)).

So you just need one Dev Hub for multiple managed packages.

Comment: Thanks let me try that